# How to control which order the EF Core run custom migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am running an application that uses custom migrations (the auto generated ones don't fit my requirements). I am trying to understand how to control in which order the Entity Framework will run those migrations. I read on some places that using timestamp on the file names will do it, but that does not work. (it runs 20190131153312_bla before 20190131153208_bla2, for example)

No matter where I look I can't seem to find information on this subject... can anyone help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Migration *file* and *class* names doesn't matter.

The order of migrations is determined by the *migration identifier* (string), which is provided by the [Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationattribute.id?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_MigrationAttribute_Id) property of the [MigrationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationattribute?view=efcore-2.1) associated with the [Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migration?view=efcore-2.1) derived classes.

EF Core tools prepend timestamp to the user supplied migration names in order to ensure proper string ordering.

Comment: You can also find the identifier mentioned above in the `.Designer.cs` file for the given migration.